# ModuleNotFoundError in python script vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHm4s.png)

In my image, you can see my project structure and code in linksUploader and imports done inside it. However I tried running it, it is giving me error as shown image.

Is it due to any extensions in vscode or issue in Ubuntu Os (23.10)?

**DataEXtractionScripts/linksUploader.py**

```
try:
   from Utils.Models import LogEntry, MangaLink
   from Utils.databaseConnection import getCollection
   from Utils.loggerSetup import loggerSetup
except ModuleNotFoundError as e:
   from Models import MangaLink
def uploadLinksFromUserInput(links: List[MangaLink], collection):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    links = [MangaLink(url="https://kunmanga.com/manga/invincible-at-the-start/")]
```

**Utils/Models.py**

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, HttpUrl

# USED in linksUploader
class MangaLink(BaseModel):
   url: HttpUrl
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xyz/MangaTrackerX/DataEXtractionScripts/linksUploader.py", line 5, in <module>
    from Utils.Models import LogEntry, MangaLink
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Utils'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xyz/MangaTrackerX/DataEXtractionScripts/linksUploader.py", line 9, in <module> 
    from Models import MangaLink
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Models'
```

I tried various ways to run but nothing works.

This is My project Structure inside Vscode

```
# MangaTrackerX/
│
├── DataExtractionScripts/
│   |── linksUploader.py
    └── __init__.py
│
└── Utils/
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── Models.py
    ├── databaseConnection.py
    └── loggerSetup.py
├── .env
├── .gitignore
├── LICENSE
├── Readme.MD
└── requirements.txt
```

Comment: Do you understand what the error is saying? Why are you expecting `Utils.Models` to be importable? Like, did you add it to `sys.path`, or if you already have `''` or `'.'` in your `sys.path`, are you in the right working directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, why not use `from Utils.Models import Mangalink` to import it like the code above.

[image]

If you do not change the import method, you can add the following content to the top of the code to indicate ***PYTHONPATH***.

```
import sys
sys.path.append("./Utils")
```